# References to generic functions

Tags: generics, kotlin

Is it possible to make reference to generic functions in Kotlin?

For example, let's say I have a function:

```
fun inline <reified T> appendToString(a: T, b: T) = a.toString() + b.toString
```

How can you reference this function? This will not compile

```
var a = ::appendToString<Int>
```

Comment: Does it work for non-inline functions ?

Comment: No, I also tried with a plain generic T (not reified) type.

Comment: I also run into this problem, and for me this workaround is fine: `var a: (Int,  Int) -> String = ::appendToString`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially you have to define the property type and then put generic functions in it. Like Max mentioned it in the question's comment section.

```kotlin
// generic function
fun <T> appendToString(a: T, b: T) = a.toString() + b.toString()

// Failed, since cannot type inference
val temp = ::appendToString

// Failed, invalid syntax, since you cannot use type parameters this way
val temp2 = ::appendToString<String, String>

// Success, valid syntax to define type, unlike previous temp2 example, and resolved the type inference issue in temp1, since you spelled it out for the compiler
val temp3: (String, String) -> String = ::appendToString
```

Or you can use `typealias` to do a work around, if you are using function as arguments:

```kotlin
typealias TypedAppendToString = (String, String) -> String

fun <T> appendToString(a: T, b: T) = a.toString() + b.toString()

fun refToFunction(appendToString: TypedAppendToString) {
    appendToString.invoke("daf", "daf")
}

fun main() {
    refToFunction(::appendToString)
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Currently it is not supported. But there is a feature request you can support if you would like to see it implemented :) [KT-12140](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12140)