# Kotlin - Generic function references

Tags: kotlin

Given the following class

```
class Foo {
    fun bar() {}
}
```

I can reference the `bar` function like so

```
Foo::bar
```

I want to be able to do this for generic functions

```
class Foo {
    fun <T> bar() {}
}
```

But the compiler throws the following error

> Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  bar(): Unit Please specify it explicitly.

How can I provide the parameter for generic function references?

**Workaround 1 (Function *proxy*)**

*Proxy is probably the wrong term here but until someone tells me otherwise...*

One approach I've been able to do is *proxy* the function, removing the generic type, but this isn't a great approach if I'm honest...

```
fun Foo.barOfInt() = bar<Int>()
```

Which can be referenced normally...

```
Foo::barOfInt
```

**Workaround 2 (Get by name)**

The second approach that seems successful, albeit still not very clean would be to build a `KClass<*>` extension that can get the method by name...

```
fun KClass<*>.getGenericFunction(name: String): KFunction<*> {
    return members.single { it.name == name } as KFunction<*>
}
```

Which I can use like so...

```
Foo::class.getGenericFunction("bar")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `T` is a phantom type (not used anywhere) so there is nothing for the type inference to latch onto and it must therefore be declared explicitly. Unfortunately as mentioned in [References to generic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691046/references-to-generic-functions), [KT-12140](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12140) is still open and there is no syntax for such a declaration with the point free method reference notation.

Creating the lambda `fun (foo: Foo) = foo.bar<Int>()` looks like your best bet currently although simply using the type `T` somewhere else in the signature would likely give the type inference enough to go off of such that this wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Aha, so it's not supported right now. I will have to use a workaround for the time being.