# Generic Top Level Function Reference

Tags: function, kotlin, reflection, reference, toplevel

How can i reference the following [function](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/SequenceBuilder.kt#L25)

```
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
public fun <T> sequence(@BuilderInference block: suspend SequenceScope<T>.() -> Unit): Sequence<T> = Sequence { iterator(block) }
```

Attempting

```
val sequenceFunction: KFunction<Sequence<Int>> = ::sequence
```

results in a compile-time error

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  sequence(block: suspend SequenceScope.() -> Unit): Sequence
> Please specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
val f: (suspend SequenceScope<Int>.() -> Unit) -> Sequence<Int> = ::sequence
```

worked

*Note*: The obtained object is some sort of a wrapper function type. Not the actual function declaration. Running [this](https://bitbucket.org/sero4/workspace/snippets/5Lb5z9) can demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to look at the parameters and the return type, and specify the function type based on that. Here's a more complex example:

```kotlin
package kotliquery

fun <A : AutoCloseable, R> using(closeable: A?, f: (A) -> R): R {
    return LoanPattern.using(closeable, f)
}
```

This function takes two parameters, an `AutoCloseable` and a function that takes the closeable and returns the generic type `R`. `using` then returns an instance of `R`.

The function type can be specified and referenced like this. `Session` implements `AutoCloseable`:

```kotlin
val u: (Session, (Session) -> String) -> String = ::using
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40691046/297331